# Overriding ModelBindingMessageProvider error messages

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core 2.2 webapi. There is a `POST` action that accepts a model. The model has a `Guid` as one of the properties. When I post this model but supply a string and not a Guid, I get a `ModelState.IsValid = false`, which is correct. The default model binding error message is `"Error converting value \"string\" to type 'System.Guid'. Path 'memberId', line 3, position 22."` This is not a friendly message that I want to return, also, this message needs to get localized to user's language. All the resources that I have read said I need to set the accessor for `ModelBindingMessageProvider` in the `AddMvC()` options. i.e.

`services.AddMvc(options => options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor((x, y) => "blah blac");`

I have set ALL of the accessors on there and it still doesn't change the default message. Anyone knows how to set those default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `InputFormatter` is throwing exception and the exception message is used for the modelstate entry. You can disable this in `services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = false;)`. This will add an empty string for the error message, which you can detect and then just display a generic message to user. I have not found a better way of doing this but this method will suffice for now.