# JsonReaderException - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I've come across many questions on StackOverflow regarding this error, none of them have achieved what I'm attempting.

What I want to do is translate the following array of error messages into something more readable

```
{
    "parent.booleanChild": [
        "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path 'parent.booleanChild', line 0, position 0",
        "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: r. Path 'parent.booleanChild', line 0, position 0"
    ]
}
```

Desired outcome

```
{
    "parent.booleanChild": [
        "Value 'True' is not valid, only 'true', 'false' and 'null' are allowed."
    ]
}
```

Example request

```
{
    "parent": {
        "booleanChild": True
    }
}
```

I have tried implementing a custom `JsonConverter` but am finding that the `JsonReaderException` is raised before the converters are executed.

Has anybody achieved something similar, that allows them to produce more meaningful & readable error messages, without implementing a custom `IInputFormatter`?

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: @Crowcoder Which section code are you interested in? This is an enterprise application using ASP.NET Core 2.2, so exact code can't be shared but I can create an MCVE, though I suspect a default out of the box ASP.NET Core service will suffice also.

Comment: You can't deserialize invalid json. Maybe you should do a replace of `True` with `true` and likewise with false before deserializing.

Comment: This isn't about deserializing invalid JSON, I understand that already, this is a question about producing a more readable error to end users instead of having 2 or 4 strings that portray the same error.

Comment: You haven't shown how you arrive at the less readable error. I don't understand the question so I'll go away now.

Comment: The less readable error is what Newtonsoft returns in a `JsonReaderException`, it's presented back to an end user with [`ValidationProblemDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.validationproblemdetails?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [`InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions.invalidmodelstateresponsefactory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which is another way of doing `if(ModelState.IsValid)` with a DRY approach.

Comment: @ColinM How are you doing the deserialization, are you doing it to a defined type or just object/dynamic? FYI it seems possible, but you might have to create a converter for the types as [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm) shows the errors can be more readable

Comment: You could intercept the error by adding an error handler to the JsonSerializerSettings. Here you get the path - `parent.booleanChild` and the error message in the ErrorContext - but not the value. So you can set the original exception as 'Handled' and throw a new one with text like "Only 'true', 'false' and 'null' are allowed values for parent.booleanChild"

Comment: @George the model is a complex POCO. Thank you both for the suggestion, I will take a look at overriding intercepting the `JsonSerializerSettings` behavior and report back here.

Comment: One more thing you can get from the error is `e.ErrorContext.Error.TargetSite` - which in this case is `Boolean ParseValue()`

Comment: @stuartd I've tried your suggestion with `OnErrorAttribute` and the `Error` property on `JsonSerializerSettings`, throwing a new exception in this code causes an `InvalidOperationException`in [the following method](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/a31156e90a14038872f54eb60ff0e9676ca4a0d8/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalBase.cs#L94). Continuing to investigate as this is definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: Must be taking a different code path from my quick test of this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4yJ5.png

Comment: I suspect this may be due to how ASP.NET Core is handling the exception that I raise. I have made some progress with `AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages` which now results in a blank/empty error message. I could handle this via `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`, similar to your code, to set the error message.

Comment: It looks like the only options are to 1) set `AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages` to `false`, 2) inherit from `JsonInputFormatter` and override [this behavior](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/04ce6cae44fb0cb11470c21769d41e3f8088e8aa/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonInputFormatter.cs#L301) or 3) Combine option 1 & handle this in `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by behavior of the `JsonInputFormatter` [`ReadRequestBodyAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/30eec7d2ae99ad86cfd9fca8759bac0214de7b12/src/Mvc/Mvc.Formatters.Json/src/JsonInputFormatter.cs#L299) method.

There are a few options I've come across for using custom error messages, none of which are elegant.

Option 1: Override `ReadRequestBody` to add a fixed error message.

```cs
public class CustomJsonInputFormatter : JsonInputFormatter
{
    private readonly IArrayPool<char> charPool;
    private readonly MvcOptions options;

    public CustomJsonInputFormatter(ILogger logger, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, ArrayPool<char> charPool, ObjectPoolProvider objectPoolProvider, MvcOptions options, MvcJsonOptions jsonOptions)
        : base(logger, serializerSettings, charPool, objectPoolProvider, options, jsonOptions)
    {
        this.charPool = new JsonArrayPool<char>(charPool);
        this.options = options;
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(
        InputFormatterContext context,
        Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (encoding == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(encoding));
        }

        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        var suppressInputFormatterBuffering = options?.SuppressInputFormatterBuffering ?? false;

        if (!request.Body.CanSeek && !suppressInputFormatterBuffering)
        {
            // JSON.Net does synchronous reads. In order to avoid blocking on the stream, we asynchronously
            // read everything into a buffer, and then seek back to the beginning.
            request.EnableBuffering();
            Debug.Assert(request.Body.CanSeek);

            await request.Body.DrainAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            request.Body.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }

        using (var streamReader = context.ReaderFactory(request.Body, encoding))
        {
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
            {
                jsonReader.ArrayPool = charPool;
                jsonReader.CloseInput = false;

                var successful = true;
                Exception exception = null;
                void ErrorHandler(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
                {
                    successful = false;

                    var path = eventArgs.ErrorContext.Path;

                    var key = ModelNames.CreatePropertyModelName(context.ModelName, path);
                    context.ModelState.TryAddModelError(key, $"Invalid value specified for {path}");
                    eventArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                }

                var type = context.ModelType;
                var jsonSerializer = CreateJsonSerializer();
                jsonSerializer.Error += ErrorHandler;
                object model;
                try
                {
                    model = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonReader, type);
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Clean up the error handler since CreateJsonSerializer() pools instances.
                    jsonSerializer.Error -= ErrorHandler;
                    ReleaseJsonSerializer(jsonSerializer);
                }

                if (successful)
                {
                    if (model == null && !context.TreatEmptyInputAsDefaultValue)
                    {
                        // Some nonempty inputs might deserialize as null, for example whitespace,
                        // or the JSON-encoded value "null". The upstream BodyModelBinder needs to
                        // be notified that we don't regard this as a real input so it can register
                        // a model binding error.
                        return InputFormatterResult.NoValue();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return InputFormatterResult.Success(model);
                    }
                }

                if (!(exception is JsonException || exception is OverflowException))
                {
                    var exceptionDispatchInfo = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception);
                    exceptionDispatchInfo.Throw();
                }

                return InputFormatterResult.Failure();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2: Perform pattern matching in [`InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions.invalidmodelstateresponsefactory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and replace the error

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path 'parent.booleanChild', line 0, position 0

Option 3: Set [`AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcjsonoptions.allowinputformatterexceptionmessages?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to false and make the assumption in the [`InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions.invalidmodelstateresponsefactory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that any blank messages will be due to serialization errors.

I am not marking this as *the* answer as I am sure somebody else will have a better idea.

I have raised a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18538) which proposes what I think may be a solution.

Other SO questions I found:

[ASP.NET Core handling JSON deserialization problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58023879/5062791)

[Overriding ModelBindingMessageProvider error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54860391/5062791)

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved something similar to what I think you refer to in your question, although it is still quite hacky. And probably very flakey.

I honestly can't believe that this isn't supported (there are many reasons I need this including security and limiting complexity of the codebase) - this especially puzzling as the new `System.Text.Json.Serialization` doesn't yet support many of the features that Newtonsoft Json offers.

My attempt follows something similar to your `Option 2` although no string pattern matching. it relies on you being able to derive a suitable message from an exception that was raised during binding (and indeed an exception existing, this wont work if the messages are not generated from exceptions.)

I did this in Asp.Net Core 3 although you could probably do something similar in 2.2.  I chose not to override the JsonInputFormatter because I found you would have to also override most of the wire-up to do so.

In my case, all validation errors are generated by a specific exception base class which has enough context to derive what type of response should be given to the user. The exception will be wrapped in a JsonSerializationException and discarded by the JsonInputFormatter because it thinks this is a runtime exception. However as you indicate the `Error` event on JsonSerializerSettings allows us to access this exception.

I save the exception and the path provided by Json.Net to a store scoped to the request, In my POC case I pass an IServiceProvider reference obtained through the service collection used at start up. In this way, we can obtain a reference to original HttpContext which then can be picked up by the InvalidModelStateResponseFactory.

My start up code looks like this:-

```
            services
            .AddControllers()
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = HandleTypedErrors)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.ApplySerializationErrorRecording(services));
    }

    private static IActionResult HandleTypedErrors(ActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var errors = actionContext.ModelState
            .Select(modelError => new
            {
                State = modelError,
                Exception = actionContext.HttpContext.RetrieveSerializationException<ErrorException>(modelError.Key)
            })
            .Where(state => state.Exception != null)
            .Select(modelError => new
            {
                ErrorField = modelError.State.Key,
                ErrorCode = modelError.Exception.ErrorCode,
                ErrorDescription = modelError.Exception.Message
            })
            .ToList();

        return errors.Any() ? new BadRequestObjectResult(errors.ToList()) : null;
    }
```

The apply error recording looks something like this:-

```
public static MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions ApplySerializationErrorRecording(this MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions options, IServiceCollection services)
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.Error += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                var context = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

                if (context == null || !(args.ErrorContext.Error is JsonException) ||
                    !(args.ErrorContext.Error.InnerException is ErrorException ex))
                    return;

                var errors = context.Items["Error"] as Dictionary<string, ErrorException> ??
                             new Dictionary<string, ErrorException>();
                errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Path, ex);
                context.Items["Error"] = errors;
            };

            return options;
        }
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, I may create a tech debt item and link to this answer (of course, marking this as the accepted answer at that point). Do you process the serialization logic in the `Error` event as well as raising your exceptions in that event for it to bubble up to the `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` delegate? I did create the [following issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18538) to get some better support for customizing the error responses as we too had a security concern with this being flagged by pen testers.

Comment: In my case an incorrect error message is bubbled to the `InvalidModelStateFactory` already as the issue happens during an implicit conversion operator which is present on our value types. But the error state doesn't have the exception - as it get filters out by the Input formatter, so all I need to do is tie the error message up to the exception using the model state key. I've updated the code with the ApplySerializationErrorRecording to show my noddy Error Handler. This has had very little testing and is just POC at this point. I do feel like none of this should be necessary.